# How to create a incremental connector on Airbyte?

Tags: python, request, data-ingestion

I am evaluating Airbyte to ingest data from multiple sources, one of them is a servicesnow API, I developed a connector using Airbyte CDK.

I am trying to implement incremental streams or slides to improve data recovery performance. since pulling everything in a single block takes a lot of resources and the aws instance crashes.

I followed other sources and set state_checkpoint_interval but it keeps bringing back all the logs in one go, it should be 100 by 100 I think so.

Does anyone have experience working with it?

I followed this documentation but I do not have results:
Incremental-Stream
https://docs.airbyte.com/connector-development/cdk-python/incremental-stream

Stream-slices
https://docs.airbyte.com/connector-development/cdk-python/stream-slices

My source code:

```py
class ServicesnowApi(HttpStream):
    url_base = "https://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/v1/"

    # Set this as a noop.
    primary_key = None
    # Save the state every 100 records
    state_checkpoint_interval = 100
    page_size = 100
    cursor_field = "sys_updated_on"

    def __init__(self, limit: str, sys_created_from: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Here's where we set the variable from our input to pass it down to the source.
        self.limit = limit
        self.sys_created_from = sys_created_from


    def path(self, **kwargs) -> str:
        # This defines the path to the endpoint that we want to hit.
        limit = self.limit
        sys_created_from = self.sys_created_from
        return f"table/incident?sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_limit={limit}&sysparm_query=sys_created_on>={sys_created_from} 00:00^active=ISNOTEMPTY"


    def request_params(
            self,
            stream_state: Mapping[str, Any],
            stream_slice: Mapping[str, Any] = None,
            next_page_token: Mapping[str, Any] = None,
    ) -> MutableMapping[str, Any]:
        limit = self.limit
        sys_created_from = self.sys_created_from
        return {"limit": limit, "sys_created_from":sys_created_from}


    def parse_response(
            self,
            response: requests.Response,
            stream_state: Mapping[str, Any],
            stream_slice: Mapping[str, Any] = None,
            next_page_token: Mapping[str, Any] = None,
    ) -> Iterable[Mapping]:
        result = response.json()['result']
        return result


    def next_page_token(self, response: requests.Response) -> Optional[Mapping[str, Any]]:
        return None
```